# Correct way to query for optional relationships using Cypher 2.0.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to figure out what the correct way is to query for additional optional relationships when returning a primary set of items (or if there is more idiomatic way to accomplish the same thing).

I've set up an example at http://console.neo4j.org/?id=747b3x.  I have three nodes, one of which HAS two tags and one IS_A thing.  I would like to query for all of the items and return the item itself as well as any related tags and things.

The result set I'm trying to create is the following:

```
Item     Tags        IS
-------  ----------  --------
1        ['A', 'B']  null
2        null        null
3        null        'foo'
```

This is what my query currently looks like:

```
MATCH (i:Item)
WHERE HAS(i.name)  // in reality, statements to narrow down i
WITH i
MATCH (i)-[?:HAS]->(t:Tag), (i)-[?:IS_A]->(s:Thing)
RETURN i.name AS item, COLLECT(t.name) AS tags, s.name AS is
```

In the console this gives a null pointer exception, but on my server it only seems to return items that have both tags and things associated with them. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MATCH (i:Item) 
WITH i 
MATCH (i)-[?:HAS|:IS_A]->(n) 
RETURN i.name AS Item, COLLECT(n.tag_name) AS Tags, n.is_name AS IS
```

If it makes sense to differentiate the types of names on `:HAS` and `:IS_A` nodes (or perhaps just duplicate the name attribute into `tag_name` as well as `is_name`) then this is workable. However, if an `Item` has no tags, then instead of a `NULL`, you will get an empty list.

Edit:

Another method you might try, although it doesn't work on the console and I don't want to start up a new DB is:

```
MATCH (i:Item)
WITH i
MATCH (i)-[?:HAS]->(t:Tag)
RETURN i, t
MATCH (i)-[?:IS_A]->(s:Thing)
RETURN i.name as item, COLLECT(t.name) AS tags, s.name AS is
```

Comment: Thanks. Turns out that `(i)-[?:HAS]->(t:Tag)` does not work, but `(i)-[?:HAS]->(t)` (note the lack of label) does work. Not sure if this is a bug or feature... I only noticed it when I went to try out your code, so thanks!